# How to paint the two last quarters of circles that are missing?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can to color the two first quarter of circles, but I can't to color the last two:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[fill=red!80] (0,0) -- +(0:1) arc (0:90:1);
\draw[fill=red!80] (0,2) -- +(0:1) arc (0:-90:1);
\draw[ultra thick]
  (0,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[ultra thick]
  (2,0)--(2,2);
\draw[ultra thick]
 (2,2)--(0,2);
\draw[ultra thick]
  (0,2)--(0,0);
\draw[ultra thick]
  (1,0) arc (0:90:1);
\draw[ultra thick]
  (1,0) arc (180:90:1);
\draw[ultra thick]
  (0,1) arc (-90:0:1);
\draw[ultra thick]
  (1,2) arc (180:270:1);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another option: use `\clip`. Basically you draw the full circles but delete the portion outside the clipping path.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\rcirc{2}        % radius
  \def\dcirc{2*\rcirc} % diameter
  \clip [draw] (0,0) rectangle ++(\dcirc,\dcirc); % clipping path
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,0/\dcirc,\dcirc/0,\dcirc/\dcirc} {
    \filldraw [fill=red] (\x,\y) circle (\rcirc);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is what the picture would actually look like without clipping (the clipping path is the dashed line):
[image]

Answer (score 5):

A short version where you fill with 'white' over red rectangle :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, ultra thick]
    \draw[fill=red!80] (0,0) rectangle +(2,2);
    \draw[fill=white] (1,0) arc (0:90:1) arc (-90:0:1) arc (-180:-90:1) arc (90:180:1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Because I like code golfing, you can replace the 4 lines with one :

```
\tikz\draw[thick,bend left=45,fill=red!80]rectangle(2,2)(0,1)to(1,0)to(2,1)to(1,2)to(0,1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Code golfing eh? (powered by Heiko's control sequence replacement!)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\foreach~in{4,1,2,3}\draw[rotate=90*~,fill=red!80,thick](1,0)|-(0,1)arc(0:90:-1);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Still room for golfing: `\tikz\draw[fill=red!80]\foreach~in{-1,1}{(~,0)coordinate(t)arc(-90:0:-~)-|(t)arc(-90:-180:~)-|(t)};`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ha! Very clever shortcut. To this day I never thought about cutting the corners of the loop like that. Thank you.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Why the ~ works in place of variable ?

Comment: `\tikz\draw[fill=red!80]\foreach~in{-1,1}{(~,0)arc(90:0:-~)-|(~,0)arc(-90:0:-~)-|(~,0)};`

Comment: @Kpym `~` is an active character, which can be defined and used as macro in most cases. One of the exceptions is `\newcommand`, which expects the token to start with a backslash.

Comment: @MarkWibrow when you add 'thick' you are still 5 characters behind percusse+HeikoOberdiek team ;)

Comment: `\def~{[rotate=90](1,0)|-(0,1)arc(0:90:-1)}\tikz\draw[fill=red!80,thick]~~~~;`, 75 characters, who's next :P

Comment: `\def~{[fill=red!80,thick,rotate=90](1,0)|-(0,1)arc(0:90:-1)}\tikz\draw~~~~;` You are @Kpym :)

Comment: @percusse I was hoping to replace `(1,0)|-(0,1)arc(0:90:-1)` with the shorter `svg{M1 1V0Q0 0 0 1Z}` but the svg units are points :( This makes me crazy!

Comment: @Kpym Hahaha. Then look into the actual `\pdfliteral`s. SVG won't cut it.

Comment: I've tided the comments here a bit, hopefully keeping the key thread.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

As announced, a one-liner with just one `\filldraw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\filldraw[fill=red,ultra thick] (0,0) -- +(0:1) arc (0:90:1) arc (-90:0:1) arc (-180:-90:1) arc (-270:-180:1) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Initial version

I first gave this solution which I liked because allowed to use the known solution to complete the problem by shifting and scaling a copy of the partial solution; however, there are some imperfections in the outcome (look closely at `(1,0)` and `(1,2)`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\filldraw[fill=red!80,ultra thick] 
  (0,0) -- +(0:1) arc (0:90:1) -- (0,2) -- +(0:1) arc (0:-90:1) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,xscale=-1]
\filldraw[fill=red!80,ultra thick] 
  (0,0) -- +(0:1) arc (0:90:1) -- (0,2) -- +(0:1) arc (0:-90:1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]